# How do i set the base to control the entire character?

Tags: rigging

I have a controller called base, but i can't seem to make it control the entire character (i want to move and rotate the character without any of the other bones deforming).

I set it as top bone in the hierarchy and parented the pelvis to it but this made it move just the pelvis. If i set it to parent all the bones in the rig all hell breaks loose (the character rotates uncontrollably).

I added the bone after i already started animating as i realized i was missing the control.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRwzq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to visualize all bone layers, then select the pelvis bone and move it (in pose mode). You'll have to set the controller bone as parent of the pelvis and of all the bones not moved by the pelvis (tipically all IK controllers and poles).

Comment: I think my rig setup was just badly designed, i tried your suggestion but that didn't work, so i just created a new object and set it as parent to the rigged object and bone system, and moved them with that. Not ideal but worked for what i needed.